# How to get all selected dropdown values for a particular Id using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple `select` dropdown menus that start with the id: package which are added dynamically by the user. My goal is to put all the selected values from these `select` dropdowns into an array. Here is the code I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    arr = new Array();

    $(document).on('change', 'select[id ^="package"]', function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
        alert(arr.join('\n')); //for testing
    });

});
```

Currently all I am doing is pushing the selected values onto the array rather than setting the values for a specific index. Therefore if I keep switching the value for a specific `select`, I will keep pushing values onto the array. How can I determine which selector I am currently in so I can get an index into the array to modify the array accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jQuery [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) method:

> translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[id ^="package"]', function() {
    var arr = $('select[id ^="package"]').map(function(){
       return this.id + " " + this.value
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yRP6R/1/)

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for?

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[id ^="package"]', function() {
     $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(i){
           arr[i] = $(this).val();
     });
});
```